# In the Berlekamp-Zassenhaus algorithm, why does one multiply with $\operatorname{lc} h$ in the recombination step? (rigorous justification)

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, factoring

Denote the polynomial to be factored by $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Here is a rough overview of what is done in the Berlekamp-Zassenhaus algorithm:

- Assume $f(x)$ is primitive and square-free.
- Choose suitable prime $p$.
- One then factors $h(x)$ in a way such that $f(x) = \prod_{i = 1}^{r}{u_i(x)}$ over $\mathbb Z_p$, and $\operatorname{lc} u_1(x) = \operatorname{lc} f(x) \bmod{p}$ while $\operatorname{lc} u_2(x) = \dots = \operatorname{lc} u_r(x) = 1$.
- Then the factors are (quadratically) Hensel lifted to modulo $p^K$ for suitably large $K$, so that $f(x) \equiv \prod u_i^{(K)} \bmod p^K$ and preserving the $\operatorname{lc}$ properties in modulo $p^K$. (Here $u_i^{(K)}(x)$, $i = 1, \dots, r$, are the lifted factors).

Finally, one attempts to retrive the factors in $\mathbb Z[x]$ from these $u_i^{(K)}(x)$. This is done (essentially) by testing whether various combinations of $u_i^{(K)}(x)$ divide $f(x)$. Here is an example pseudocode from Computing, Suppl. 4, 95–113 (1982) by E. Kalfoten:

---

[image: Kalfoten pseudocode for combination step in BZ factorisation]

---

**Question**

Notice that at first, $h(x) := f(x)$. This is updated if a factor $g(x)$ is found to $h(x) / g(x)$.

In the forall loop, instead of simply taking combinations of $u_i^{(K)}(x)$ and testing for divisibility, one further multiplies the combination of $u_i^{(K)}(x)$ by $\operatorname{lc} h(x)$, reduces modulo $p^K$, and takes the primitive part. I can see that taking the primitive part can only be advantageous (and is compulsory because $f(x)$ is primitive, for instance). However, why multiplying by $\operatorname{lc} h(x)$ guarantees success is unclear to me.

I have seen specific examples where without this multiplication the factors of $f(x)$ are not retrieved, and with the multiplication, they are retrived.

- However, what is the rigorous yet *assumingly* simple explanation why the multiplication by $\operatorname{lc} h(x)$ and reducing modulo $p^K$ works? Why does it fix things?

Comment: $\operatorname{lc}$ and $\operatorname{ldcf}$ is the leading coefficient.

Comment: I'm anything but sure, but ... We can bound the coefficients of a putative factor. If $p^K$ is large enough those coefficients will match with their balanced remainders modulo $p^K$. But if the leading coefficient of a factor is not $\pm1$, then the coefficients of the factor *normalized to become monic* are not integers, and the process fails.

Comment: I may be wrong, but if for example the factor is $3x-5$ then without the leading coefficient you have $x-5/3$. Good luck finding $5/3$ modulo $p^K$! It will never stabilize when you keep increasing $K$. The coefficients $3$ and $-5$ on the other hand...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm not sure either :-), but... I don't think non-integer coefficients can arise unless the pp is omitted in the forall cycle. When we factorise over $\Bbb Z_p[x]$, we actually factorise lc$(f)^{-1}f(x)$. The factors $u_i(x)$ can be assumed to be monic because lc$\(f)^{-1}f(x)$ is monic. To get $u_1(x)$ to have the proper lc, we multiply by $u_1(x)$ by $\operatorname{lc} f$. During lifting steps (at least in linear lifting, the chapter quoted does lifting quadratically), the $u_i^{(k)}$ can always be found to have both integer coefficients and satisfy the constraints on lc-s.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It is also the case, I think, that if we multiply $u_{i_1}^{(K)} \cdots u_{i_m}^{(K)}$ by $\operatorname{lc(f)}$ that the coefficients can exit the $-p^K/2, p^K/2$ range. This is because $K$ is chosen to be big enough that the coefficients on any actual integer factor $g(x)$ of $f(x)$ are in that range, but $u_{i_1}^{(K)} \cdots u_{i_m}^{(K)}$ is not necessarily an actual factor of $f(x)$ over the integers. (2/3)

Comment: For example, say that $p := 13, K := 2$. After lifting, we could have $u_2^{(2)}(x)$ such that its free term is $-84$. Also say that the free term of $f(x)$ is $1$. Then $u_2^{(2)}(x)$ cannot be a factor of $f(x)$. But if $\operatorname{lc} f = 2$, we multiply $u_2^{(2)}(x)$ by $2$. Its linear term is now $-84 \cdot 2 = 1 \bmod{13^2}$. And thus, $2u_2^{(2)}(x)$ could *potentially* be a divisor of $f(x)$. I suspect this kind of wizardry is going on here, but as I say, I cannot put my finger on the essence of what is happening, nor am I sure :). (3/3)